# Replace a variable I (0) by an I (1 ) to test cointegration

Tags: cointegration

I'm building a VAR to model the relationship between production of the economy and some of its determinants. One of the endogenous variables of the model is inflation as a measure of macroeconomic stability. However, all my variables are I (1) except inflation which is stationary. I want to test cointegration by Johansen test, but I can not because inflation is I (0). It occurred to me that instead of using inflation is I (0), using the CPI (consumer price index) is I (1). Someone had this problem, or something related. Please, I can give his opinion.
Thanks for the help

PS: The method Pesaran, Shin and Smith to contrast cointegration in variables of a different order of integration is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

When modelling economic time series it is actually common to use the price index, such as the CPI, $p_{t}$. Then the first difference can be considered as inflation, $\Delta p_{t}$ so using the CPI is in fact more appropriate than using inflation. On another note then there is nothing wrong with modelling $I\left(0\right)$ and $I\left(1\right)$ variables jointly in a CVAR framework. It would just mean that the stationary $I\left(0\right)$ variables could be considered as an equilibrium relationship on their own.

Another thing to note is that often prices are viewed as $I\left(2\right)$ and hence inflation will be $I\left(1\right)$. If this is the case then it is more apropriate to start out with a CVAR $I\left(2\right)$ model but this is not applicable to you since you state that inflation is $I\left(0\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please let me ask you another question. In my model VAR I have the following endogenous variables Log (GDP) log (financial deepening) log (openness) log (public spending) log (CPI) and am considering adding terms of trade index (which is stationary I (0) in trend) as an exogenous variable. And as deterministic variables I added an intercept. Let me know if I can use the test to trace Johansen cointegration test. The critical values ​​are right ?

Comment: My size displays of 56 and I am applying the correction proposed by Cheung and Lai (1993) for small samples. This adjustment is made by multiplying the value of the trace test by the factor (t-nk) / t where t is the number of data, n is the number of variables in the system and k is the number of lags included. The variable index of terms of trade to be considered exogenous I have included contemporary form. In this case, as I apply the adjustment ?.I'm using the Eviews.I beg you to help me with this.

Comment: First of all then you have very few observations. I am not familiar with the Cheung and Lai (1993) correction but there is a Bartlett correction for small samples and there is an article in the most recent Econometrica volume which discusses rank selection based on bootstrapping.

Second, if you include a variable which you think only affects the variables in the system but is not affected by them then you can include this variable as an exogenous variable. This can also be tested in the model before. If you think that terms of trade fits this description then go ahead. Otherwise include it as

Comment: an endogenous variable.

If you have determined the rank for the full system, including terms of trade then you do not need to re-estimate the rank. If on the other hand you just assume exogeneity then you need to run the rank test again but the rank test assumes that the weakly exogenous variable is a random walk which I just saw that yours is not.